# filter special data from the quoted string and generate output sequence number from for-each condition

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, foreach, xslt-2.0

I really worked many ways to solve it but I couldn't able to finish it.

Code snippet [Click here for code and result](http://xsltransform.net/gWEaSvp/2)

My request payload is

```
<process>
<TransactionType>
    <data_xml>
        <transaction>
            <parent>{"26":"27"}</parent>
            <sub_documents>
                <transactionLine>
                    <parent_doc_number>2</parent_doc_number>
                    <bidvalue>LOV</bidvalue>
                </transactionLine>
                <transactionLine>
                    <parent_doc_number>26</parent_doc_number>
                    <bidvalue>EATY</bidvalue>
                </transactionLine>
                <transactionLine>
                    <parent_doc_number>26</parent_doc_number>
                    <bidvalue>CLD</bidvalue>
                </transactionLine>
                <transactionLine>
                    <_parent_doc_number>31</_parent_doc_number>
                    <bidvalue>YOND</bidvalue>
                </transactionLine>
                <transactionLine>
                    <_parent_doc_number>6</_parent_doc_number>
                    <bidvalue>CHEG</bidvalue>
                </transactionLine>
            </sub_documents>
        </transaction>
    </data_xml>
</TransactionType>
```

and the excepted output would be

```
<Ref>EATY</Ref>
<LineSeq>1</LineSeq>
<Ref>CLD</Ref>
<LineSeq>2</LineSeq>
```

My xslt codeis

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/process/TransactionType/data_xml/transaction/sub_documents/transactionLine">
  <xsl:variable name="PDocNum" select="parent_doc_number"/>
   <xsl:if test="contains(/process/TransactionType/data_xml/transaction/parent,PDocNum)">
   <Ref>
       <xsl:value-of select="bidvalue"/>
   </Ref>
   <LineSeq>
       <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
   </LineSeq>
   </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The logic what i am trying is from the **parent{"26":"27"}** attribute value i will check whether the **parent_doc_number** is there like using contains function. Here the fist problem is the request <parent_doc_number> not contains quotes("") so with out I pass that will give even the <parent_doc_number>2</parent_doc_number>. But this is not the excepted.

The sequence also not generating properly. I spent lot of time and not finished. Please help me out on this tricky thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you describe is not entirely clear. Assuming that the `parent` element lists the `parent_doc_number` values of all the `transactionLine` elements you want to output, enclosed in quotes and separated by a colon, you could use:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="tx" match="transactionLine" use="parent_doc_number" />

<xsl:template match="/process">
    <output>    
        <xsl:for-each select="key('tx', tokenize(translate(//parent, '{}&quot;', ''), ':'))">
            <Ref>
                <xsl:value-of select="bidvalue"/>
            </Ref>
            <LineSeq>
                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </LineSeq>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <Ref>EATY</Ref>
   <LineSeq>1</LineSeq>
   <Ref>CLD</Ref>
   <LineSeq>2</LineSeq>
</output>
```

---

Note that `contains()` is not a good test to use here, because `26` also contains `2` and `6`. You could use something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//transactionLine[contains(//parent, concat('&quot;', parent_doc_number, '&quot;'))]">
```

but using a key in the opposite direction is both more elegant and more efficient.

Comment: But it's showing error when put the above condition.
 System function concat() cannot be called with one argument

Comment: code snippet  http://xsltransform.net/gWEaSvp/2

Comment: I did not consider it necessary to test code that I do not recommend . I have fixed it now. Note that if you use `xsl:if` instead of a predicate, the `position()` function will count ALL  `transactionLine` elements.

Comment: Yes Michael it's working. I agree with you on the xsl:if using it giving all count... Thanks the way respond and solve this.